# Api auth middleware is not working on serve

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5.5 application
I am able to login with API but unable to access routes with "auth:api" middleware.

Sending headers like

1 . Accept = application/json

2 . Authorization = Bearer eyJ0eXAi.....xxxxxxxx

In api.php

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function(){
    Route::post('user', 'Api\Auth\PassportController@getDetails');
}
```

This working on local but not on server.

Checked error_log file and laravel.log file. But no luck.

Don't know whats wrong.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What error message are you getting, have you checked your server error logs? If it's working on local but not your production server it could be something as simple as missing some dependencies via Composer? Is the access token you are using on the server incorrect? Could be a lot of things without more code/an error log.

Comment: Yes @XanT , no logs are there, I am getting Unauthenticated message from App\Exceptions\Handler@unauthenticated class

Comment: Are you using the right token? did you set an authentication code?

Comment: yes @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz

Answer (score 1):

After hours of searching and moving many lines of code:
`php artisan config:clear`
Works for me!

Idea from: https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/452