# Api auth middleware is not working on serve but working in local

Tags: laravel

[Api auth middleware is not working on serve](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49920284/7627785)

I have an exactly same problem. Please help me.

Comment: are you sending headers content-type: application/json

Comment: I have sent headers  Accept : application/json  not content-type.

Comment: can you post your postman or Arc screen shot that how you are sending request

Answer (score 0):

Did you run php artisan passport:install on server? Do you have valid oauth keys in storage folder on server??

if not then run the command on server by using ssh or any other accessible server terminal:

`php artisan passport:install`

Comment: Yes i did. when I request with https://domain/oauth/token with all credentials I get valid access token  and refresh token.
But when I request with Bearer + access token always I get "massege": "Unauthenticated"